# Pre-Calc Center of a Circle

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the center of the circle $x^2+y^2+12y – 45=0$?

I know the center of the circle is $(h,k)$ but I am unsure on how to solve this equation. What steps do I need to do in order to find the center? Help!

Comment: Veronica, instead centering your knowledge you are duplicating your questions.  What for?

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2+y^2+12y-45=0$$

Bring the $45$ to the other side;

$$x^2+y^2+12y=45$$

And complete the square for ($y^2+12y$) by finding $y^2+12y+c$ where $c=36$;

$(y^2+12y+36)-36$ (since we added $36$ into the equation, we need to subtract $36$ as well)

Factor the ($y^2+12y+36$);

$$(y+6)^2-36$
and plug it back into the equation;

$$x^2+(y+6)^2-36 =45$$

And move the $36$;

$$x^2+(y+6)^2 =81$$ or
$$(x+0)^2+(y+6)^2=81$$

So looking at the equation, we find the center to be $(0,-6)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since we have (by $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$)
$$y^2 + 12y = y^2 + 12y + 36 - 36 = (y+6)^2 - 36$$
You get
$$0 = x^2 + y^2 + 12y - 45 = x^2 + (y+6)^2 - 81$$
So you see the answers for both of your questions now?

---

In case you still don't:
Your circle has a radius of $\sqrt{81} = 9$ and is centered at $(0, -6)$.
You should really look at this topic again.